# Uses of Mockit.reset() on a mock object

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is it right to use Mockito.reset() in @Before method for mock objects which is being used in more than test method in the same test Class as shown below.

```
public class SampleTest {   

  @Mock
  private CustomRepository customRepo;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    Mockito.reset(customRepo);
  }

  @Test
  public void test1(){
  ......

  given(customRepo.someMethod()).willReturn(Answer1);
  ......
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(){
  ......

  given(customRepo.someMethod()).willReturn(Answer2);
  ......
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reset the mock because JUnit/Mockito creates a new instance of `SampleTest` and the mock object for each test.